# if else statement from database record laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel-5

i want to create if else from database record.

for example : i've record "1" in "status" row.

```
"if status = "1" 
echo Show Button
else 
don't show button"
```

what code in controller and view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put in the view your if

```
 @foreach ($itens as $item)
    @if ($item->status == 1) 
    <input type="button"/>
    @endif
@endforeach
```

In your controller you don't need to care about it

Comment: thanks! i changed @if ($item->status) and it's worked i don't know why lol xD

Comment: is because 1 == true. if your status is boolean it's ok, but if it is a integer see to another values... 2, 3... is what you whant

Answer (score 0):

You can use **Laravel Blade Template Control Structures** for this

i.e.

```
@if($status == 1)
...
<!-- HTML Code to generate button -->
...
@endif
```

Read more [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/blade#control-structures)